# I need a neat data structure suggestion to store a very large dataset (to train Naive Bayes in Python)

Tags: python, data-structures, machine-learning, spam-prevention

I am going to implement Naive Bayes classifier with Python and classify e-mails as Spam or Not spam. I have a very sparse and long dataset with many entries. Each entry is like the following:

1 9:3 94:1 109:1 163:1 405:1 406:1 415:2 416:1 435:3 436:3 437:4 ...

Where 1 is label (spam, not spam), and each pair corresponds to a word and its frequency. E.g. 9:3 corresponds to the word 9 and it occurs 3 times in this e-mail sample.

I need to read this dataset and store it in a structure. Since it's a very big and sparse dataset, I'm looking for a neat data structure to store the following variables:

- the index of each e-mail
- label of it (1 or -1)
- word and it's frequency per each e-mail
- I also need to create a corpus of all words and their frequency with the label information

Any suggestions for such a data structure?

Comment: If you say "store it in a structure", do you mean a structure which is in memory ? Or do you want to store it on disc ?

Comment: You seem to have left out a key element: how big is your dataset? How many records and how many words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would generate a class

```
class Document(object):

    def __init__(self, index, label, bowdict):
        self.index = index
        self.label = label
        self.bowdict = bowdict
```

You store your sparse vector in `bowdict`, eg

```
{ 9:3, 94:1, 109:1,  ... }
```

and hold all your data in a list of `Document`s

To get an aggregation about all docs with a given label :

```
from collections import defaultdict

def aggregate(docs, label):
    bow = defaultdict(int)
    for doc in docs:
        if doc.label == label:
           for (word, counter) in doc.bowdict.items():
                bow[word] += counter  
    return bow
```

You can persist all your data with the `cPickle` module.

Another approach would be to use http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html. You can represent a bow-vector as a sparse matrix with one row. If you want to aggregate bows you just have to add them up. This could be pretty faster than simple solution above.

Further you could store all your sparse docs in one large matrix, where a Document instance holds a reference to the matrix, and a row index for the associated row.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume you didn't care about multiple occurrences of each word in an email, then all you really need to know is (that is, your features are booleans):

For each feature, what is the count of positive associations and negative associations?

You can do this online very easily in one pass, keeping track of just those two numbers for each feature.

The non-boolean features means you'll have to discretize the features some how, but you aren't really asking about how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Yelp/sqlite3dbm
http://packages.python.org/sqlite3dbm/

This is like a python dictionary except that it stores everything you give it on disk and so, is persistent! This is not going to bloat up tons of memory because its writing stuff to disk. You can have one program set up these files, and a different one use them for classification, without having to worry about serialization problems.

You can cleanly model the first problem as

```
doc_to_info[doc_id] = {'label': 'label_0', 'word_freqs': {'this': 3, 'is': 4, ...}}
```

You can model the second problem as

```
word_to_freq[word] = {'label_0': 42, 'label_1': 314}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with some relational database (SQLite is easy to set up), and use the following table structure:

```
Word
-----
Number    INT   -- The word number in your data
Word      TEXT  -- The word itself


Entry
-----
ID        INT  -- Some number to make it unique
Spam      INT  -- -1 or 1 as you described


Entry_Word
----------
EntryID   INT  -- The entry this row corresponds to
WordNo    INT  -- The number of the word
Frequency INT  -- The number of occurences of the word
```

To get the entries you can use

```
SELECT ID, Spam
FROM Entry
```

To get the word frequencies for some entry, you can use:

```
SELECT WordNo, Frequency
FROM Entry_Word
WHERE EntryID = ?
```

To get the word frequency corpus, you can use:

```
SELECT
    WordNo,
    SUM(MIN(0,Spam*Frequency)) AS NotSpamFrequency,
    SUM(MAX(0,Spam*Frequency)) AS SpamFrequency
FROM Entry
INNER JOIN Entry_Word ON EntryID = ID
GROUP BY WordNo
```

You could also include the word itself, if you want:

```
SELECT
    Word,
    WordNo,
    SUM(MIN(0,Spam*Frequency)) AS NotSpamFrequency,
    SUM(MAX(0,Spam*Frequency)) AS SpamFrequency
FROM Entry
INNER JOIN Entry_Word ON EntryID = ID
LEFT JOIN Word ON Number = WordNo
GROUP BY Word, WordNo
```